# Procedure broken when string has a number

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I have written this procedure in SQL Server:

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[cazacliente2]
    (@vbusca nvarchar(60), @bo int) 
as
   if  @bo= 1  
   begin
      select idcliente, nome, endere, tel, pedido from Vw_Conscliente
      where  nome like @vbusca  
   end

   if @bo = 2
   begin 
      select idcliente, nome, endere, tel, pedido from Vw_Conscliente
      where endere like @vbusca 
   end

   if @bo = 3
   begin 
      select idcliente, nome, endere, tel, pedido from Vw_Conscliente
      where tel like  @vbusca  
   end

   if @bo = 4
   begin
      select idcliente, nome, endere, tel, pedido from Vw_Conscliente
      where pedido like @vbusca
   end
```

and this code in asp.net :

```
  {
        string valorC = "%" + TextBox1.Text + "%"; numo = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
        string valorB = valorC.Replace(" ", "%"); 

        switch (numo)
        { 
            case "Nome":  num3 = 1;  break;     case "Endereço": num3 = 2; break ;
            case "Telefone": num3 = 3 ; break;  case "Pedido": num3 = 4; break ;
        }

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "cazacliente2";
        SqlParameter valor = new SqlParameter("@vbusca", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
        SqlParameter num = new SqlParameter("@bo",SqlDbType.Int );
        valor.Value = valorB   ; num.Value = num3 ; 
        cmd.Parameters.Add(valor); cmd.Parameters.Add(num);

        if (conex1.State  == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {  conex1.Open(); }
            cmd.Connection = conex1;
        try
        {
            GridView1.EmptyDataText = "Nao se" + numo.ToString()  +"encontraron registros";
            GridView1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { throw ex; }
        finally
        { conex1.Close(); }

    }
```

When I pass the string `afonso pena` the procedure returns all the data just fine, but when I pass in `afonso 60`, it returns an error, and when I pass a name that is not in the database it breaks again, it is like the part catch does not work.

Comment: What error does it throw?

Comment: Taking into account that you are getting an error just in case the stored procedure returns no data please test you code under this particular condition.

Comment: Look at the code I gave you below; it reduces redundancy by using dynamic SQL.  UNIT test with a the cases that are breaking.  That guarantees to PROC works with your data.  Then debug the C# program.  Use PRINT in the PROC if you want to see the @statement string.

Answer (score 1):

When your question involves an error, it's a great idea to include the error message you see in your question. As it's difficult to debug without knowing the error message, try the following to narrow down where the problem might be.

Try restructuring your code to catch any possible errors before you try databinding your `GridView`:

```
{
    /*
     * put the try at the top of the block to catch exceptions
     * that may occur before you bind the GridView's datasource
     */
    try
    {
        numo = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
        string valor = "%" + TextBox1.Text.Replace(" ", "%") + "%"; // no reason to NOT one-line this

        /*
         * This would probably be easier to maintain if DropDownList1
         * was bound to an enumeration of these values:
         *     DataTextField="someTextField"
         *     DataValueField="someCorrespondingNumericField"
         * If bound that like above, your switch statement becomes:
         *     Integer.Parse(DropDownList1.SelectedValue, numo);
         * and numo then contains 1, 2, 3, or 4 thus eliminating the need for the variable num3.
         */
        switch (numo)
        { 
            case "Nome":
                num3 = 1;
                break;
            case "Endereço":
                num3 = 2;
                break;
            case "Telefone":
                num3 = 3;
                break;
            case "Pedido":
                num3 = 4;
                break;
        }

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "cazacliente2";

        // add parameters and set values all at once
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@vbusca", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 60).Value = valor;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@bo",SqlDbType.Int).Value = num3;

        if (conex1.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            conex1.Open();
        }
        cmd.Connection = conex1;

        GridView1.EmptyDataText = "Nao se " + numo.ToString()  +" encontraron registros";
        GridView1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        conex1.Close();
    }
}
```

Also, your stored procedure can be written a little more cleanly:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[cazacliente2] (
    @vbusca nvarchar(60)
    , @bo int
) 
AS
    SELECT  idcliente
            , nome
            , endere
            , tel
            , pedido
    FROM    Vw_Conscliente
    WHERE   CASE
                WHEN @bo = 1 THEN nome
                WHEN @bo = 2 THEN endere
                WHEN @bo = 3 THEN tel
                WHEN @bo = 4 THEN pedido
            END LIKE @vbusca
```

Answer (score 0):

I would move the wild card to the TSQL instead of the C#.  That way you can test it independently.

Your definition shows a maximum length of 60.

```
@vbusca nvarchar(60)
```

Is the parameter you passing from C# to SQL greater than that?  You should look at the local variable on a break point in Visual Studio to confirm this is not true.

Also, replacing spaces inside the parameter means that the logical words in side the parameter just need to match in any order.  Is this what you want?

'afonso 60' **matches** 'afsonso when to the store to by milk that cost 60 dollars'

Check out MSDN for wild card usage:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189454.aspx

I used dynamic SQL below since it reduces the overall code size.

Sample code change:

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[cazacliente2] (@vbusca nvarchar(32), @bo int) AS

BEGIN

  -- Local variables
  DECLARE @statement VARCHAR(MAX);
  DECLARE @field VARCHAR(MAX);
  DECLARE @expression VARCHAR(MAX);

  -- Make the expression (exact match of @vbusca)
  SET @expression  = '%' + REPLACE(@vbusca,'''', '''''') + '%';

  -- Optional way (match words in @vbusca in order)
  -- SET @expression  = '%' + REPLACE(REPLACE(@vbusca,'''', ''''''), ' ', '%') + '%'

  -- Which field
  SELECT @field =
    CASE @bo 
      WHEN 1 then 'nome'
      WHEN 2 then 'endere'
      WHEN 3 then 'tel'
      WHEN 4 then 'pedido'
      ELSE 'nome'
    END;

  -- Make up the dynamic SQL
  SET @statement = 'select idcliente, nome, endere, tel, pedido ' + 
      ' from Vw_Conscliente where ' + @field + ' like ' + @expression;

  -- Execute the SQL statement
  EXEC @statement;

END;
```

I will be adding a caution advisory to any dynamic TSQL that I write in the future.   Here is a link on how to handle injection issues.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953(v=sql.105).aspx

Updated SP to handle issues by reducing search pattern size and handling single quotes inside the parameter.

Comment: This is a beautiful example as to why SqlInjection is the top 1 in the OWASP risks for years... :) You should avoid making dynamic sql with parts that are made from user input. Other than that - it does work :)

Comment: If it is a fixed drop down list in C#, how do you get SQL injection?  On the other hand, if it is a combo box, I would change the code.

Comment: I have re-write the procedure like CRAFTY DBA says , and returns is not possible find the stored procedure 'select idcliente, nome, endere, tel, pedido from Vw_Conscliente WHERE nome like %ALEJANDRO%'.

Comment: Try 'EXEC sp_executesql @statement' instead.  I did not create a test environment for the code.  I do like pete's solution since you do not have to worry about SQL inject.  However, I would add an else clause.  What happens when you pass a 5 to the code?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the best solution so far, no SQL injection, does handle when invalid @bo is passed, defaults to nome.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[cazacliente2] (@vbusca nvarchar(60), @bo int) 
AS
    SELECT  
        idcliente
      , nome
      , endere
      , tel
      , pedido
    FROM    
      Vw_Conscliente
    WHERE   
        CASE
            WHEN @bo = 1 THEN nome
            WHEN @bo = 2 THEN endere
            WHEN @bo = 3 THEN tel
            WHEN @bo = 4 THEN pedido
            ELSE nome    
        END LIKE @vbusca;
```